# Why do I get a "-1" when I downvote others' answers?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, down-votes

Well, in [How does reputation work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238) post, I've read that if you put a downvote on others' answers you'd get "-1" on your reputation. Yet, I cannot think of a potential reason for this as long as the downvoted answer really deserves a downvote.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Couple of related older posts: 
[Why does the person who is downvoting an answer get a downvote himself?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20484), 
[-1 for downvote?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11512) and
[Deduction in rep for downvoting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25753).

Comment: Because we want you to be sure that the answer you're downvoting is bad, rather than use this as a tool for revenge, that will ultimately dissuade people from participating in the site. (I don't mean that *you*, VIVID, are doing any of that, of course. This is an abstract "you".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a network-wide setting; note that it used to be the case that [downvoting questions cost reputation too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90324/295232). For answers, this feature is kept to prevent the so-called [Slowest Cheater In The East](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22368/295232) effect; users would downvote answers just because they competed with theirs. By making downvotes not free, this problem has (mostly) disappeared.

Note that when the answer is deleted (usually via the Low Quality Posts review queue) because it's a *really bad answer*, you'll get your reputation back. Also, when the answer is edited in a shape not being worthy of a downvote anymore, you can undo your vote and you gain your reputation back.

Comment: [Several questions on this topic](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/25753) are closed as duplicates of this one: [Deduction in rep for downvoting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25753). So I would not be surprised if the same happens to this question. The links to [meta.se] posts which you've posted here aren't mentioned there (unless I missed something) - so your answer adds something new. So if this question gets closed, maybe you could repost this answer on the older one...?

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks. It *is* mentioned (sort of) in Travis' answer: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25764/228959. I'll edit in a link.